# Microsoft SQL Server IP/server login

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have installed many SQL Server setups but I want to know how to install SQL Server without an instance name i.e. i want to connect to SQL Server with IP or server name only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing an instance and connecting to an instance of SQL Server are two different things.
Every time you attempt an SQL Server installation you have to specify an instance (create a new one or select an existing one)

Connecting to an instance is a different thing.
For example if you want to connect to an instance through MS Management studio without writting the name of the instance you can define the connection in following manner:

```
ComputerName\IP,port
```

e.g:

```
MyPC\192.168.1.1,1433
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you need to install SQL Server as the default instance on the machine.  When it is set as the default instance you no longer need to specify an instance name when connecting to it.